# Python:All the same values ​enter the array with "for ~ in"

Tags: python

I am now trying to store an array with a id in a new array.
Here is the code.

```py
for pre in predict:
　　　　　#10 loops
        x1, y1, x2, y2, id = int(pre[0]),int(pre[1]),int(pre[2]),int(pre[3]),int(pre[4])
        if (id not in ids):
            ids.append(id)
            for cdn_list[id] in contours_list:
                print(cdn_list)
```

The contents of contours_list are this.

```
[array([[[20,  0]],
       .......
       [[76,  0]]], dtype=int32)], [array([[[20,  0]],

       [[19,  1]],

       .......

       [[103,  0]]], dtype=int32)].....
```

And the result.(All values ​​will be the same!!)

```
{10: [array([[[20,  0]],
     .......
       [[76,  0]]], dtype=int32)], 9: [array([[[20,  0]],
     .......
        [[76,  0]]], dtype=int32)], 8: [array([[[...
     .......
```

This is the desired result.The values ​​are different(note [103,0]).

```
{10: [array([[[20,  0]],
     .......
       [[76,  0]]], dtype=int32)], 9: [array([[[20,  0]],
     .......
        [[103,  0]]], dtype=int32)], 8: [array([[[...
     .......
```

I tried several methods, but none of them worked.Why are the values ​​all the same? Thank you.

Comment: You are always printing the same array, which is `cdn_list`. It is not changed during your loop. Your iterator contains a variable which I assume is not what you expect it to do.

Comment: What does the variable `cdn_list` contains? Can you create a minimal example code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Python has weird rules for scoping the iteratee variable in for loops.

```
for cdn_list[id] in contours_list
```

are you sure you don't want

```
for cdn_list in contours_list[id]
```

instead ?

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Akari it's impossible to tell what you are trying to do, without more context. All we can say is that an indexed expression as the iteratee, like you did, is almost always wrong.

If this is homework, you should disclose so.